# When windows is unlocked, trigger save and exit and log off user

Tags: excel, vba

i have a vba macro running and i will then just lock windows, macro continuing run.

What i want to do : Upon unlocking windows

Action : save workbook, exit excel file, and then log off user.

Im using 64-bit excel, so this code needs to be changed a bit, but i found this thread for logging off :

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "User32" ( _
  ByVal uFlags As Long, _
  dwReserved As Long) As Long

Private Const EWX_LOGOFF = 0

Sub Logoff()
Dim Retval As Long

    Retval = ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, 0&)
    If Retval = 0 Then MsgBox "Could not log off", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Logoff"

End Sub
```

"Attention For a 64-bit Excel you have to adapt the api declarations. Often you only have to add PtrSafe and replace Long with LongLong" --- how do i do that?

//
I also found this thread for checking if computer is locked, but this is also in 32bit
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/check-if-system-is-locked-or-unlocked-using-vba.646623/

How would you put the whole code together to save,exit,and log off
Thank you for your valuable help

Comment: VBA is not the best tool for the job here. You would be much better off using VB.NET or C# to write your monitoring application. It could monitor for any event and do any list of things that you can imagine.

Comment: `EWX_LOGOFF` needs to be of long type, and it is currently of `Integer` type. Integer is 16-bit in Excel, and Long is 32-bit which is macine native. NVM, I see it is `ByVal`, so it is converted anyway (I hope).

Comment: @HackSlash i understand, but i just want upon unlocking to save,exit,log off.. thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare PtrSafe Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
```

No need of any `LongLong` variable declaration...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method without using APIs

```
Sub ExitWindows()
    'shutdown after 60 sec
    'Shell "shutdown.exe /s /f /t 60"
    
    'Log off
    Shell "shutdown.exe /l"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "User32" ( _
  ByVal uFlags As Long, _
  dwReserved As Long) As Long

Private Const EWX_LOGOFF As Long = 0
Private Const SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OTHER as Long = 0

Sub Logoff()
Dim Retval As Long
    
    Retval = ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OTHER)
    If Retval = 0 Then MsgBox "Could not log off", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Logoff"

End Sub
```

<sub>Reference: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ExitWindowsEx.html</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Long variable to a LongPtr variable instead of a LongLong variable.
But not all Longs are changed to LongPtrs.
This page explains about that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/win32api_ptrsafe-with-64-bit-support

If you want to lock the windows,

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function LockWorkStation Lib "user32" () As Long
Sub LockAndSave()
    LockWorkStation
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

If you want VBA to detect when a user locks Windows, it's very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the lock of the Windows,

```
'These function must be put in the standard moudle , or an compile error will occur.
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtrW Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProcW Lib "User32" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WTSRegisterSessionNotification Lib "wtsapi32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification Lib "wtsapi32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long

Private Const GWLP_WNDPROC As Long = -4
Private OrgProc As LongPtr
Private Const NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION As Long = &H0
Private Const WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE As Long = &H2B1
Private Const WTS_SESSION_LOCK As Long = &H7

Public Function WindowProc(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    WindowProc = CallWindowProcW(OrgProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
    If uMsg = WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE Then
        If wParam = WTS_SESSION_LOCK Then
            Debug.Print "The session is being locked."  'Place the code here to Save the workbook and 
            EndWatching  'If you delete this line , the Excel will crash when the session is locked again.         
        End If
    End If
End Function

Sub StartWacthing()
    'This function has to be called once in Workbook_Open event or whereever you want.
    If OrgProc Then
    Else
        OrgProc = SetWindowLongPtrW(Application.hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)
        WTSRegisterSessionNotification Application.hWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION
    End If
End Sub

Sub EndWatching()
    'You should call this function in Workbook_BeforeClose event.
    'Or excel will crash when you close the book.
    If OrgProc Then
        SetWindowLongPtrW Application.hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, OrgProc
        OrgProc = 0
        WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification Application.hWnd
    End If
End Sub
```